# How to make a prop required based on condition typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

```
interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   gender: string;
   vaccinated: 'yes'|'no';
   vaccineName?: string
}
```

This interface describes vaccineName is optional and other properties are required. If property vaccinated is **yes** I need to make vacccineName property as required

```
<Person name='abc' gender='m' vaccinated='yes' />
```

Now this should throw error as vaccineName is required.
Is this possible in react typescript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TypeScript's [discriminated unions](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) to get compiler-time support for exactly what you're looking for.

```
interface VaccinatedPersonProps {
   name: string;
   gender: string;
   vaccinated: 'yes';
   vaccineName: string
}

interface UnvaccinatedPersonProps {
   name: string;
   gender: string;
   vaccinated: 'no';
}

type PersonProps = UnvaccinatedPersonProps | VaccinatedPersonProps;

function Person(props: PersonProps) {
  if (props.vaccinated === "yes") {
    // vaccinated!
    console.log(props.vaccineName);
  } else {
    // unvaccinated
  }
};
```

this article provides a more thorough write up: https://blog.andrewbran.ch/expressive-react-component-apis-with-discriminated-unions/

Comment: This is working but intellisence shows this error.

Property 'vaccineName' does not exist on type 'PersonProps'.
  Property 'vaccineName' does not exist on type 'UnvaccinatedPersonProps'

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescrit-v4e3q

this is the sandbox link you can checkt here

Comment: You must check for the value `"yes"` explicitly in order to discriminate between the two types. Checking for just `props.vaccinated` is checking for "truthy" and both "yes" and "no" strings are truthy. Fixed sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescrit-forked-c2k2y